# How show Banner Ads on Newspaper Webview Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, webview

How show Banner Ads on Newspaper Link "Webview" Android Eclipse
I already set Admob "Banner Ads and Interstitial Ads" on my Project. Interstitial Ads Work Correctly but Banner Ads not Show on Webview. 
**Here my Java & xml Code** 
**Details_Newspaper.Java**

```html
package com.nasir.newspaper;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class Details_Newapaper extends Activity {

 WebView mWebview;
 
 AdView mAdView;
 private InterstitialAd interAd;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // Adds Progrss bar Support
  this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
  setContentView(R.layout.details_newapaper );
  
  // For Banner Ads View
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
  
  // For Interstitial Ads View
  interAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
  interAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
  
  AdRequest adRequest_FC = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  interAd.loadAd(adRequest_FC);
  interAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onAdLoaded() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    displayInterstitial();
   }
  });
  
  getOverflowMenu();
    
  // Makes Progress bar Visible
  getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON); 
    
  mWebview = new WebView(this);

  mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
  mWebview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  //Zoom Control on web (You don't need this 
                //if ROM supports Multi-Touch  
  mWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //Enable Multitouch if supported by ROM
  
  
  final Activity Activity = this;
  
  mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
         {
          //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
          Activity.setTitle("Loading..... Please Wait");
          Activity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded
          
          // Return the app name after finish loading
             if(progress == 100)
              Activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
           }
         });

  mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
     String description, String failingUrl) {
    Toast.makeText(Activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });

  String customHtml = getIntent().getStringExtra("Newspaper_Name");
  mWebview.loadUrl(customHtml);
  setContentView(mWebview);
  mWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

 }
 
 
//  On Back Button Press, Go to Website Back
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  if (mWebview.isFocused() && mWebview.canGoBack()) {
   mWebview.goBack();
  } else {
   super.onBackPressed();
   finish();
  }
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 // For Interstitial Ads View 
 public void displayInterstitial() {
  
  if (interAd.isLoaded()) {
   interAd.show();
   
  }
 }

    /** Called when leaving the activity */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called when returning to the activity */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
 
 // inflate for action bar
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.refresh_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
 
    // handle click events for action bar items
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
 
            case R.id.refresh:
                showToast("Refresh was clicked.");
                return true;
 
            
 
//            case R.id.share:
//                showToast("Share was clicked.");
//                return true;
// 
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
 
    // put the other two menu on the three dots (overflow)
    private void getOverflowMenu() {
 
        try {
 
           ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
           java.lang.reflect.Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
           if(menuKeyField != null) {
               menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
               menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
 
     }
 
    // so that we know something was triggered
    public void showToast(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 
}
```

**details_newspaper.xml**

```html
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|fill_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
       
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1528948212400372/9325301249" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```